# Can you use an 'beforeunload' listener in an export default function? If so how?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

All examples I am seeing online are using React Components. I am a newbie to react.  So any explanation will be helpful, and what I should do to achieve this.

```
export default function Review() {
...

useEffect(() => {
console.log("useeffect called")

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", save());

}, []);

...

return (...);
```

Here is a CodeSandbox.io link.  Here you will find that I have 2 pages 1 home the other dashboard.

When I go to dashboard.  I get the Alert.  But Leaving Dashboard I do not get the Alert Message.  beforeunload is not working how I expect it to.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-8uvvi?file=/

Comment: That looks like a React component to me. What is the issue?

Comment: It doesn't call the beforeunload when I leave the page. Alot of examples I see online are utilizing the extends React.Component

Comment: Normally you'd use the `window` object to attach a listener to. Why can't you use it?

Comment: can you put up the code for how the  `Container` component is defined ? I suspect Container is not forwarding the ref to a div.

Comment: @DrewReese window does work actually I was wrong about that I thought it gave me an error last time. Just tried it now. But still does not run beforeunload listener when leaving page

Comment: @kumarmo2 import Container from "@mui/material/Container";

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @DrewReese I added a codesandbox.  I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to call a function when a page/component is about to be unmounted is to add it as a return from your `useEffect()`. For example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return(() => save())
  }, []);
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-vty0e?file=/Dashboard.js)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing an `onbeforeunload` callback, you are immediately invoking the alert.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("useeffect called");
  // subscribe event
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", alert("HI"));
}, []);
```

Create/define a callback that does one, or more, of the following:

- Prevents the default on the event object
- Assigns a string to the event object's `returnValue` property
- Returns a string from the event handler.

[window.beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

> **Note:** To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in `beforeunload` event handlers unless the page has
> been interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.

Code suggestion

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (e) => {
    // Cancel the event
    e.preventDefault(); // If you prevent default behavior in Mozilla Firefox prompt will always be shown
    // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
    e.returnValue = "";

    // ... business logic to save any data, etc... before the window unloads
    save();

    return "";
  };

  // subscribe event
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
  };
}, []);
```

[image: Edit can-you-use-an-beforeunload-listener-in-an-export-default-function-if-so-how]